# Read file byte by byte using read()

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to wrap my head around the `read()` system call.

How can I read an actual file **byte by byte** using `read()`?

The first parameter is the file descriptor which is of type `int`.
How can I pass a file to the `read()` call?

Comment: `read(fd, &buffer, num_bytes)`

Comment: You can use [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) to open a file and get the file descriptor that can be used later as an argument to `read`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You open the file with [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html); you pass the file descriptor returned by `open()` to [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html).

```
int fd;
if ((fd = open(filename, O_RDWR)) >= 0)
{
    char c;
    while (read(fd, &c, 1) == 1)
        putchar(c);
}
```

There are other functions that return file descriptors: [`creat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/creat.html), [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html), [`socket()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/socket.html), [`accept()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html), etc.

Note that while this would work, it is inefficient because it makes a lot system calls.  Normally, you read large numbers of bytes at a time so as to cut down on the number of system calls.  The standard I/O libraries (in `<stdio.h>`) handle this automatically.  If you use the low-level `open()`, `read()`, `write()`, `close()` system calls, you have to worry about buffering etc for yourself.

Comment: is byte the same size as char since it looks like you are saving the byte to a char variable?

Answer (score 1):

The last argument to `read()` is the number of bytes to read from the file, so passing `1` to it would do it. Before that, you use `open()` to get a file handle, something like this (untested code):

```
int fh = open("filename", O_RDONLY);
char buffer[1];
read(fh, buffer, 1);
```

However, it's usually not recommended to read files byte by byte, as it affects performance significantly. Instead, you should buffer your input and process it in chunks, like so:

```
int fh = open("filename", O_RDONLY);
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
read(fh, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

for (int i=0 ; i < BUFFER_SIZE ; ++i) {
   // process bytes at buffer[i]
}
```

You would finally wrap your reads in a loop until EOF is reached.

Comment: How does this code determine how much data was successfully read?  Certainly the return value of `read()` needs to be checked.

Comment: You are correct. I did not provide a full example, but after wrapping the read in a loop it would be necessary to check read's return value and process only that many bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of read() system call to Kernel is this (In simple english)

read (from this file (file descriptor), into this buffer in the memory, of this size )

Example: Read a character by character  from a file which is in the disk into this buffer BUFF

```
int fd // initialize the File Descriptor 
fd = open ("file_name", O_RDONLY); //open a file with file name in read only mode.
char BUFF;

read (fd,&BUFF,sizeof(char)); // read file with file descriptor into the address of the BUFF buffer in the memory of a character of size CHAR data type.
```